# PWA Remote Install based on Url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

It's possible to install a Progressive Web App with a button inside an external website with Javascript ?

I have a VueJS App, Hosted in EC2 AWS with Docker and Traefik.
I have a webapp who listing PWA, but I want to know if it's possible to install external PWA inside my website.

Best regards

Comment: Please elaborate your question with more details, like what technology you are using in frontend, backend, how do you host your app, what type of app you have developed and how you want it to install, etc :)

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: You can do that by creating an app that will install the PWA for you, this app will download the source file of your pwa and create directory, generate subdomain (if necessary) create database, assign the database with that, etc.

Comment: The user must be ON the HTTPS site you want installed, and they must say yes to the pop-up. AND your website must pass all the criteria for a valid PWA. You can use the Chrome Lighthouse tool to help you with that.